# Username and password for MAMP PRO

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I need help with the proper sequence and locations for changing the root username and password in MAMP PRO, not MAMP, I can get that to work fine.

I was using MAMP (free), and had no problem updating the username and password from root to a username and password, and it worked fine to log into phpmyadmin. I upgraded to MAMP PRO for more host capabilities and have been having trouble with this error. i know it is something to do with the password, but can't figure it out.

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

here is what i tried:
i uninstalled MAMP and MAMP PRO and deleted the file folders in my C drive.
then i started a fresh install.

it installed fine and i could log into phpmyadmin with the generic root settings. from there i changed the username and password in the root account.

Then i went to the MAMP PRO folder to look for the configure.inc.php file to update the username and password, but it is not in there. there is no bin or phpmyadmin folders in it. there is in the MAMP folder, but it does not help if i change anything in there.

so, after that i cannot get back into phpmyadmin in MAMP PRO unless i uninstall it, delete the file folders and reinstall again. maybe i need to have both mamp and mamp pro installed, but i tried that with my first install of mamp pro and it didn't work.
i am sure this will get some down votes, but i just need some help at this point and MAMP customer service has not yet responded.

thank you!

Comment: It’s long time ago I upgraded from MAMP to PRO and I can remember I had also many problems but I cannot remember details. So here are just a few thoughts. Did you check that pro is using 3306 as port for MySQL? Perhaps it uses an other one and you must change it? Can you access MySQL from the terminal? Just try a mysql -u rootname -p password in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i figured it out and will put the answer here for anyone else with this problem in the future. in MAMP Pro you stop the server and then click on the mysql client on the left in hosts and a window pops up so you can change the password. i could not change the root username, but just added a new user with my name and my password, so all the hosts are protected and not giving me the error. i was then easily able to add it to valentina studios.

Comment: Do you know if MAMP Pro is using its own files? I'm thinking about upgrading to MAMP Pro, but when I changed the password there and then checked the files I used to manually change in free MAMP, nothing had changed.